# Exception case if the system does not install browser

Tags: java

I use command line of window to launch the URL on Java:

```
try { 
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start firefox \"" + url + "\"");  
}
catch() {   
    // exception
}
```

I have a issue how to check FireFox browser is installed or not? If don't check browser, how to handle the exception case by Java code. Because, Window OS will handle this issue and show the message popup, I don't want to see this popup.

Comment: Have you tried maybe looking for the executable first?

Comment: Why FireFox in particular?  For more reliable browser launching, use `Desktop.broswe(URI)`.  But if you insist on starting a new process.. See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: Thank Andrew, that is a good ideas..=)

Answer (score 2):

You can open the browser in a more platform independent way and catch the `IOException`. See the reasons in the snippet

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        // will open the default browser
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create("http://example.com"));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // if the user default browser is not found, 
        // or it fails to be launched, 
        // or the default handler application failed to be launched
        ... your exception handling goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: This code only launch url by default browser. I want to launch by multiple browser. Thanks

Comment: @baopham Ok this was not clear from your example. Would you only run the `firefox.exe` if it's found in `PATH`? Because it's not neccessary to be there. How you want to solve the case where it's installed (keep in mind there might be a portable version installed) and not in `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if an application is not installed, an `IOException` will be thrown (Cannot run program "your program").

How to handle the exception is up to you, you can inform the user or log the error and exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors, Assuming you have shortened it for posting question.
below code will execute commands and prints errors silently

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] commandsToExecute = { "cmd.exe", "/Q",/* this command will put most of the stuff to silent mode.*/
        "/c", "firefox" }; /* no need start before firefox*/
        Process proc = runtime.exec(commandsToExecute);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String message = null;
        System.out.println("info messages:\n");
        while ((message = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
        buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
        System.out.println("error messages:\n");
        while ((message = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: :you can change commandsToExecute  to :  String[] commandsToExecute = { "cmd.exe","/Q",/* this command will put most of the stuff to silent mode.*/
         "/c", "start chrome www.google.com" }; and run. And after change "chrome" by another browser which is not installed and run again. This message popup error will be shown by window os. How to exit this message ?